# LINQ query not returning desired result as string. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

My code:

```
public string LocName(string locID)
    {
        var name = (from a in idc.Locations
                    where a.ID.ToString() == locID
                    select a.Name).Single();
        return name;   
    }
```

I need it to return the name of the Location that matches the ID as a string for a TextBlock. Instead it returns no elements, I have checked that the ID is correct so it should return at least one element.

I have also tried:

```
where a.ID == new Guid(locID)
```

as well as

```
.First()
.FirstOrDefault()
```

have tried returning the result as an element and databinding to that but still - no elements.

What is the error???

Comment: Does idc.Locations contain any results?

Comment: try where `a.ID.Contains(locID)`

Comment: use String.Equals(row.Name, "test", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) for case-insensitive equal operation.

Comment: Single() would throw an exception if your result would return less or more than one record. First() would also throw exception if there ware no rows. So what is the code you tested and what was the exact result?

Comment: Check the case sensitivity. I generally avoid comparing strings using ==.

Comment: If i was you i would first check the data types in the database ... did you change them after dragging the table to the context if yes delete and re-drag again, then try what you are trying with First or FirstOrDefault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must be a casing issue if the data is there, you should always use `ToUpper()` as that is optimised for string equality checks.

Also you should always use `FirstOrDefault` as `Single` will throw an exception if there are more than one matches and `First` will throw an exception if there are no matches. Try:

**EDIT**: I've also added `Trim` on the inputted value to sanitise the spaces. I've also added a null check on the `locID` parameter as that would blow up if it was passed is as null. Lastly, I added a `??` (coalesce) on the `return` statement just incase it is returning null and you're performing other things on that string (such as `Trim` or `ToLowerCase`) as that would result in an exception.

```
public string LocName(string locID)
{
    if (locID == null) return string.Empty;

    var name = (from a in idc.Locations
                where a.ID.ToString().Trim().ToUpper() == locID.Trim().ToUpper()
                select a.Name).FirstOrDefault();

    return name ?? string.Empty;   
}
```

Comment: Same point here; if there was a white space i guess (where a.ID == new Guid(locID)) would avoid what you are talking about, right ?

Comment: @IssaQandil Check my edit, I've added a `Trim` to disregard the white space on the inputted value. This would be okay if the the `locID` was a GUID, but I don't think that's the case here? Not sure :)

Comment: If i would use Trim i would put it on the other side :)

Comment: @IssaQandil Yeah good point, best to be super safe! Edited that to include thanks :)

Comment: @xhedgepigx No problems, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Well firstly `Single()` will throw an exception if there are more than one matches to the query. I advise using `FirstOrDefault()` if you re expecting more than one answer back.

Also I would try using `Trim()` and `ToUpper()` to get rid of any whitespaces/case issues which might be preventing the strings from matching.